# finding total ways of XORing an array of integers to produce zero

Tags: algorithm, math

If we have an array of integers then how can we find the number of ways that they be XORed so that the result is 0 . Here at each step only one integer(i) can be decreased by any amount say d such that (i-d)>=0 . E.g for the integers `11,15,8` we can `decrease 11 to 7` so that 7^15^8 =0 . Similary `15 can be reduced to 3` such that 11^3^8 = 0 and `8 can be reduced to 4` such that 11^15^4=0 . Hence total ways is 3

**My approach**: to this is for each integer , go on decreasing it and at each step XOR it with remaining integers in the array , if the result is 0 , break. Check this for all integers and get the total ways. But this is 0(n^2) . Is there any efficient way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can XOR all integers in your array, then in loop XOR the result with each of your integers (it will "remove" that integer from all because `x^x` is always 0). As a result you'll get XOR of the other members and that's the number to be replaced (because `x^x` is always 0).

```
    int[] a = new int [size];
    //initialize 'a' array
    int[] b = new int [size];
    int all = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++)
        all=all^a[i];

    for(int i =0; i< size; i++)
        b[i] = all^a[i];
```

In `b[i]` you'll get the number to be replaced with `a[i]` to get zero.
I edited my answer and tried, it works. This is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to finding k numbers in an array of length that sum to x.

For k=1: Obvious. Find elements that are equal to 0

For k=2: Sort the numbers and for each number a check if 0^a exists in the array

For k=3: Sort the numbers and for each pair of numbers a and b check if a^b^0 exists in the array

For k=4: Calculate xors of every two numbers in the array and sort. And for each pair of numbers a and b check if a^b^0 exists in the sorted list

so on

For k=1, complexity is O(n), k-2: nlogn, k=3: n^2logn, k=4: n^2logn and so on.